# Inputing GPS Coordinates into an array

Tags: java, arrays, gps

I have 100 GPS Coordinates i want to put into an array, but i am not sure on how to X and Y (latitude and longitude) in one data.

```
    int coord = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(coord);
    double[][] gps = new double[coord][coord];

    for(int i = 0; i <= gps.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <=gps[i].length;j++) {
            gps[i][j]= input.nextDouble();
            gps[i][j]= input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("--");

        }       
    }
```

Comment: You'll run into an error is you use i <= gps.length; The array only has from 0 to gps.length - 1 entries.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand clearly what you want , is it something like that :

```
    int nbrCoord = 100 ;
    double[][] gps = new double[nbrCoord][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < nbrCoord ; i++) {

            gps[i][0]= input.nextDouble();
            gps[i][1]= input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("--");

        }       
    }
```